# Preferred way to test against many discrete values?

Tags: c++

I have the following scenario:

```
variable in {12, 4, 999, ... }:
```

Where there are about 100 discrete values in the list. I am writing a parser to convert this to C++, and the only ways that I can think of to do it are 100 case statements, or 100 if ==

Is one preferred to the other, or is there an all round better way to do this?

I should clarify, the values are constant integers. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If the maximum value of any one of your discrete values is small enough a `std::vector<bool>` of flags set true or false depending on whether that entry is in the list should be pretty optimal - assuming the values occur with approximately equal probabilility.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to arrange the values in order and use binary search to check whether a value is contained in your collection.

You can either put your values in a vector in sorted order using `std::lower_bound` for the insertion point and then use `std::binary_search` to test for membership, or you can put your values in an `std::set` and get that feature for free (using `std::set::find()` for membership testing).

There are minor performance considerations that may make either option preferable; profile and decide for yourself.

A second approach is to put your values in a hash table such as `std::unordered_set` (or some kind of static equivalent if your values are known statically).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the values are constants, you can certainly use a `switch` statement. The compiler will do this pretty efficiently, using either a binary search type approach or a table [or a combination of table and binary search]. A long list of if-statements will not be as efficient, unless you sort the numbers and make a binary search type approach - a switch-statement is much easier to generate, as the compiler will sort out the best approach to decide what numbers are in the list and which ones aren't.

If the values are not constants, then a switch-statement is obviously not a solution. A bitmap may work - again, depending on the actual range - of the values are a large range, then that's not a good solution, since it will use a lot of memory [but it probably is one of the fastest methods, since it's just a case of dividing/modulo with a 2^n number, which can be done with simple `>>` and `&` operators, followed by one memory read].